# ExceptionFilters in WebAPI never get hit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to catch errors coming from one of my controllers.  Elmah is not catching them so in trying to find out why, I reduced the problem to the simplest form which excludes Elmah.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("foo")]
public HttpResponseMessage Foo() 
{
    throw new Exception("test");
}


protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilter());
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

public class UnhandledExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) {
        dosomething(); //It never reaches here
```

Note: a proper JSON error is emitted to the client.

Comment: Your looks good. Please check your custom filter class UnhandledExceptionFilter.cs. Please verify your setting link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add`, go to the `Register` method in the `WebApiConfig` class and do `config.Filters.Add(new ...());` instead, that works for me.